# OAuth2 AuthorizationServer and Rest Service

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm using dotnetopenauth and asp.net mvc3 to build a rest service client.  I'm using the lastest dotnetopenauth beta 4.  Is there an example showing how to build a mvc 3 resource server?

I have a client calling Client.RequestUserAuthorization(new[] {""}) which sends off the authorization request.  When the authorization callback fires, I call the following method Client.ProcessUserAuthorization().  That method raises this error "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."  I'm not sure what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try browsing to the authorization server's access token endpoint using Internet Explorer on the same computer.  You'll likely see a warning about an invalid certificate.  That's what the error you're seeing is coming from.

To solve it, you need to either obtain a signed certificate from a root authority, or you need to add the certificate to your Trusted Certificates store on your computer.